# Decoding the Yahoo Finance JSON Code

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

So I found this URL to fetch data but I cant seem to access the JSON of what I need. Here is my code so far.

```
<?php

$url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AAPL";

$result = file_get_contents($url);//allow_url_fopen  turned on in php. ini file


// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($result, true);


print_r($resp['optionChain']['result']['expirationDates']);


?>
```

I took the url and used a site to neatly format the code.
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

But still no luck. Any suggestions?

**P.S I have used the Google API code and Lottery API codes in JSON format in the past but I cant seem to get this one lol Weird huh**

Comment: Have you tried with cURL ?

Comment: I can get the contents but I cant access the specific array. Trying to access the ['expirationDates']

Comment: Figured it out. It's this line instead of the line I posted earlier.
$resp['optionChain']['result'][0]['expirationDates']

Comment: Now how do I answer my own question officially since I been put on hold. lol